# GitHub Actions checkout@v3: where is repo downloaded?

Tags: github-actions, commit

I am working with GitHub Actions to build code on Windows, Linux, and MacOS. I use <strike>`actions/commit@v3`</strike> `@actions/checkout@v3` to download my repo to each server. However, I do not know where the repo gets downloaded. I have to `curl` other files and add them to the repo folder for the build to work.

Does anyone know where repos are downloaded on each server (Windows, Linux, and MacOS) with <strike>`actions/commit@v3`</strike> `@actions/checkout@v3`? I'm having trouble finding anything in the documentation. If the path is set in an environment variable, I would prefer to use that instead of hard coding the path for each server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The environment variable you're looking for is `GITHUB_WORKSPACE`.

> The default working directory on the runner for steps, and the default location of your repository when using the [`checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action. For example, `/home/runner/work/my-repo-name/my-repo-name`.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables